# Async HTTP request using GIO

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, gio

I would appreciate an example on how to perform an async HTTP POST request using Python's GIO binding.

**Edit**: Example sought without using Twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using Twisted Deferred objects is available on [James Henstridge's blog](http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2009/01/06/twisted-gio/).

Comment: eswald: edited my question: I do not want to rely on Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not HTTP POST (just GET), but it is using Gio to asynchronously request a URL, with a callback that processes the resulting data when it's done downloading.

https://github.com/robru/gottengeography/blob/65505bd0cf0060ec7397849e7c62c231367c7f1d/gg/datatypes.py#L242