# Threaded UDP Listener Function

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, udp

I'm pretty new to Python, so I apologize if my problem is amateurish.

I'm trying to make a simple program that allows a user to see UDP messages that are being broadcast. In order for the program to not lock up, I of course need to create a separate thread to listen for the broadcast.

Before I attempted to implement threading, the program worked great. It just waited for UDP messages and displayed them in the `TextView` when it received one. Of course, this locked up the main thread.

Here is my code: (Yes, I know there are several irrelevant issues with my code, but please ignore them. e.g., I never close the `socket`. I will address these issues later.)

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import threading

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk
except:
    print("GTK not available!")
    sys.exit(1)


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("UDPListener.ui")
        dic = {"on_mainWindow_destroy" : self.quit,
             "on_listenButton_clicked" : self.startThread,
         "on_stopListenButton_clicked" : self.stopListening}
        self.builder.connect_signals(dic)

        self.listenerThread = threading.Thread(target = self.listen)

    def startThread(self, widget):
        self.listenerThread.start()

    def listen(self):
        bufferSize = 1024                                                          
        IPAddress = "0.0.0.0"
        IPAddress: 0.0.0.0
        portNumber = 50000
        udpClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        textView = self.builder.get_object("messagesReceivedEntry").get_buffer()
        textView.text = textView.get_text(textView.get_start_iter(),textView.get_end_iter())

        textView.set_text("Listening...")

        try:
            udpClient.bind((IPAddress, portNumber))
            udpClient.setblocking(0)
        except:
            print "Cannot connect."

        try:
            while True:
                result = select.select([udpClient],[],[])
                message = result[0][0].recv(bufferSize)
                print message
        except:
            print "Cannot receive message"

    def quit(self, widget):
        sys.exit(0)

    def stopListening(self, widget):
        pass

gui = GUI()
gtk.main()
```

The code will run and everything runs ok, but it never prints any messages (I broadcast them myself).

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to J.F. Sebastian's answer, I altered my code to include the following:

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import threading
import gobject

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk
except:
    print("GTK not available!")
    sys.exit(1)

gobject.threads_init()

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, UDPClient):
        self.udpClient = UDPClient

        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("TestUDPListenerREORG.ui")
        dic = {"on_mainWindow_destroy" : self.quit,
             "on_listenButton_clicked" : self.startThread,
         "on_stopListenButton_clicked" : self.stopListening}
        self.builder.connect_signals(dic)

        self.textView = self.builder.get_object("messagesReceivedEntry").get_buffer()
        self.textViewText = self.textView.get_text(self.textView.get_start_iter(),self.textView.get_end_iter())

        self.listening = False
        self.listenerThread = threading.Thread(target = self.listen)

    def startThread(self, widget):
        self.listenerThread.start()
        pass

    def listen(self):
        try:
            self.udpClient.connect()
        except:
            print "Cannot connect."
        try:
            while True:
                result = select.select([self.udpClient.client],[],[])
                message = result[0][0].recv(1024)
                print message
                gobject.idle_add(self.updateGUI, message)
        except:
            print "Cannot receive message"

    def updateGUI(self, message):
        print "updating..."
        self.textView.set_text(self.textViewText + "\n" + message)
        print message

    def quit(self, widget):
        self.udpClient.close()
        sys.exit(0)

    def stopListening(self, widget):
        pass



class UDPClient:
    def __init__(self, IPAddress, portNumber):
        self.IPAddress = IPAddress
        self.portNumber = portNumber
        self.bufferSize = 1024

        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.bind((self.IPAddress, self.portNumber))
            self.client.setblocking(0)
        except: print "Cannot connect."

    def close(self):
        try:
            self.client.close()
        except:
            pass

udpClient = UDPClient("0.0.0.0", 50000)
gui = GUI(udpClient)
gtk.main()
```

So far everything runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model I find that works well for multithreaded gtk applications is to run all GUI code in the main thread. The only method from gtk that is run in a background thread is `gobject.idle_add()` to schedule gui callbacks to be executed in the main thread.

Put `gobject.threads_init()` somewhere at the top of the module before you run any other gtk code.

[Here's an example for Gtk 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926265/4279) but the principle is the same for Gtk 2. [Another example](https://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712).

An alternative is to use something like `gobject.io_add_watch()` and avoid using multiple threads.

Comment: @Jordan.CarrollCS: it is not enough to add `gobject.threads_init()` if you run arbitrary GUI code in the background thread. Look at the examples I provided where it *is* enough. Read [Multi-threaded GTK applications – Part 1: Misconceptions](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness) otherwise.

Comment: I implemented the new changes. Could you explain why it is "not enough" and verify I have implemented your suggestions correctly? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jordan.CarrollCS: The code related to thread-handling is ok. See [the faq for the explanation](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq20.006.htp&req=show). Other code have some issues unrelated to the question e.g., missing `self.` in the `quit()`.

Comment: I know there are other problems in the code, I am only worried about the threading right now. Thanks again for the help.